# Can I carry my computer as a carry-on on a international flight?

Tags: international-travel, hand-luggage

I am going to be traveling overseas, Jordan to be specific. I would like to place my computer in my carry-on. Are there any specific rules or instructions considering I am traveling overseas/international?

Comment: I believe the US is the only country that doesn't allow this at the moment. I always carry my laptop (I hope you mean laptop as well) with me, so it doesn't get damaged.

Comment: I think the US still only disallows carry laptop et al. from 6 specific countries and Jordan is not one of them.

Comment: I just took an international flight 3 weeks ago and was fine taking it as a carry on.

Comment: @Henrik The ban never covered countries as such but specific airlines/airports combo and Royal Jordanian flights from Queen Alia International Airport were in fact among those impacted.

Comment: It seems the question is a bit ambiguous. One answer covered the recent ban on anything larger than a phone and another one dealt with carrying a desktop computer, which one of these are you interested in?

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk UK also has specific ban in place - even stricter than the on in the USA.  For example, USA now allows laptops in carry on for Turkish Airlines flights, while UK still does not.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the recent ban only covered flights *to* the US and [has just been lifted as far as Royal Jordanian is concerned](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-airlines-electronics-jordan-idUSKBN19U0OV) so you should be fine. [A ban is still in place for flights *to* the UK](http://www.rj.com/en/news/title/3842.html) from Queen Alia Airport.

In general, laptops are allowed on international flights so it should be perfectly fine on other flights.

Answer (score 0):

The rules apply to any electronics and carry on. It must fit within the size limit and be within the weight limit too (if any, check with the airline but if you [fly Delta there is none](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/during-your-trip/carry-on.html) on *most* flights).

The potential difficulty when travelling with a standard computer as opposed to a laptop is that one is supposed to be able to show that it is working. Since you cannot carry a UPS with you, it being a giant battery, you will have to plug it in at security if requested, so be sure to have electric plug adapters and a voltage-switching power-supply, if you are goingthrough a place with different electrical standard.

Note that sometimes you are requested to gate-check a bag even though it fits within the official limit, so make sure it is packed suitably to be handled by anyone just in case. If your computer uses HDDs with moving platters, take them out and carry them personally since they are the most fragile. Even if asked to power the computer on, it will no longer boot but still show some output.

It is a good idea to have a proof-of-purchase for the return since customs in your home country may want to verify that you are not importing new electronics. In some countries, you have to declare items above a certain value when going in, so the receipt can be useful there. Still, be prepared to justify this more than once. Just two weeks ago, I was flying with a computer and was asked by customs and by security what it was and why I had to bring my own.